# Error in web app, "Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version 11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...". Where to download updates?

Tags: iis, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am a beginner Support Tech (much newb) assisting in setting up SQL Server Reporting Services for clients.  I have experienced this error when accessing the web page on an IIS/app server that is connecting to a separate SQL Server where Reporting Services is installed.  I have read about installing the Report Viewer 2012 runtime download as well as other feature pack installations to resolve this error.  However, I have not seen a definitive answer on whether these get installed on the SQL server or the server hosting the application.  I have seen this same error on multiple client machines so I am looking for a quick fix/update that can be run on these machines to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Reportviewer is a control used to render a report without relying on Reporting services.  So, whenever the report is rendered in an application, ReportViewer is required on the computer that hosts the application.  If the application simply provides a link to a report that is hosted in reporting services, ReportViewer is not needed.  In your case, ReportViewer needs to be installed on the IIS server.